# problems with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, texshop, bibdesk

I have tried to make biber to work on my machine, unsuccessfully. I have searched all over and have read all the biblatex-biber related posts, but nothing seems to do the trick. Here is a Minimal (Not working) Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../../bibliographies/example}


\begin{document}
let's cite \cite{ho1995}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it as it is here, using TexShop, by doing the Latex -> Bibtex -> Latex usual path (I previoulsy modified the Preferences -> Bibtex engine from bibtex to biber) I get the following message:

```
dhcp109128:myfolder Laura$ biber exampleBiber
INFO - This is Biber 1.6
INFO - Logfile is 'exampleBiber.blg'
INFO - Reading 'exampleBiber.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '../../bibliographies/example' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find '../../bibliographies/example'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

HOWEVER, if I change the backend from biber to bibtex and change the preferences again, I obtain a perfectly good file. I get the same issue if I try to run it in a terminal window, and again, if I run bibtex instead of biber (changing the backend each time), it works perfectly fine

Things that I have tried:

-I tried modifying the file above by adding the line 
    % !BIB TS-program = biber
at the very top, nothing happened...

-I tried updating my packages (as was suggested to me before): I am running TexLive 2013, biber 1.6, texshop 3.26
I am using bibdesk 1.6.1.

I think there might be a problem in the way bibdesk is savign the bibliography. For reference, I put the bib file at the end.
Any ideas? thanks in advance

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/

%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@article{ho1995,
Abstract = {Treatment of infected patients with ABT-538, an inhibitor of the protease of human immunodeficiency virus type 1 (HIV-1), causes plasma HIV-1 levels to decrease exponentially (mean half-life, 2.1 +/- 0.4 days) and CD4 lymphocyte counts to rise substantially. Minimum estimates of HIV-1 production and clearance and of CD4 lymphocyte turnover indicate that replication of HIV-1 in vivo is continuous and highly productive, driving the rapid turnover of CD4 lymphocytes.},
Address = {Aaron Diamond AIDS Research Center, NYU School of Medicine, New York 10016.},
Author = {Ho, D D and Neumann, A U and Perelson, A S and Chen, W and Leonard, J M and Markowitz, M},
Cin = {Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):193. PMID: 7746311; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):193-4; author reply 198. PMID: 7746312; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):194; author reply 198. PMID: 7746313; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):194-5; author reply 198. PMID: 7746314; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):195; author reply 198. PMID: 7746315; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):195-6; author reply 198. PMID: 7746316; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):196; author reply 198. PMID: 7746317; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):197; author reply 198. PMID: 7746319; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):197-8; author reply 198. PMID: 7746320; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):198; author reply 198. PMID: 7746321; Nature. 1995 Jan 12;373(6510):102. PMID: 7816085; Nature. 1995 May 18;375(6528):197; author reply 198. PMID: 7605485},
Crdt = {1995/01/12 00:00},
Da = {19950203},
Date = {1995 Jan 12},
Date-Added = {2013-09-05 18:53:13 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-09-05 18:53:13 +0000},
Dcom = {19950203},
Doi = {10.1038/373123a0},
Edat = {1995/01/12},
Issn = {0028-0836 (Print); 0028-0836 (Linking)},
Jid = {0410462},
Journal = {Nature},
Jt = {Nature},
Language = {eng},
Lr = {20061115},
Mh = {Antiviral Agents/therapeutic use; CD4 Lymphocyte Count/drug effects; CD4-Positive T-Lymphocytes/cytology/*virology; HIV Infections/drug therapy/immunology/*virology; HIV Protease Inhibitors/therapeutic use; HIV-1/*physiology; Humans; Kinetics; Ritonavir; Viremia/drug therapy/*virology; Virion/physiology; *Virus Replication},
Mhda = {1995/01/12 00:01},
Month = {Jan},
Number = {6510},
Own = {NLM},
Pages = {123--126},
Pl = {ENGLAND},
Pmid = {7816094},
Pst = {ppublish},
Pt = {Journal Article; Research Support, Non-U.S. Gov't; Research Support, U.S. Gov't, P.H.S.},
Rn = {0 (Antiviral Agents); 0 (HIV Protease Inhibitors); 0 (Ritonavir)},
Sb = {IM; X},
Status = {MEDLINE},
Title = {{Rapid turnover of plasma virions and CD4 lymphocytes in HIV-1 infection.}},
Volume = {373},
Year = {1995},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/373123a0}}
```

Comment: Add `.bib` to your bib file name in the `\addbibresource` command.

Comment: thank you Alan! it worked, can you formally reply so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `\addbibresource` command in `biblatex` can in fact open other types of resources than  `.bib` files (most notably,  URLs, and experimentally `RIS`, and some XML  formats), the file extension `.bib` is required.  This is quite different from the `\bibliography` command (which it replaced) in which the extension was implicit.

So the solution to your problem is to use:

```
\addbibresource{<your-bib-file>.bib}
```